# Change other list items' CSS when hovering an item

Tags: jquery, css, hover, siblings

How to change the other items' CSS when hovering a list item? I mean, when i hover `Item 1` i want the **others** to have, lets say, lover opacity to make an highlight effect. I'd prefer pure css but if it's not possible also appreciate jquery. Thanks.

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Like changes the un hovered ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ul:hover li {opacity: 0.5;}
ul li:hover {opacity: 1;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CTfUL/1/

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery solution would be `$(ul.li:not(:hover))`, but it is definitely possible with CSS, as @Shomz said.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('li').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).siblings().css(...);
 });
```